# What is the selector class for div inside another div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply styles for Menu class. However, when I'm writing some CSS properties to the menu the styles are not applying. How to select the exact CSS class div inside another div that to div inside header like this code below

```
<section class="showcase">
        <header>
            <img src="assets/images/logov2.png" alt="company-Logo" style="width:160px;height:20px;">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="Access">
                Get Early Access
            </div>
        </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could yopu include your CSS code, such that we can diagnose your problem coorectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the tag `header` as the start point to reach other selectors.

```css
header>img {
  height: 220px;
  width: 300px;
}

header>.menu {
  background-color: red;
}

header>.Access {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase">
  <header>
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554232456-8727aae0cfa4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=735&q=80" alt="company-Logo">
    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="Access">
      Get Early Access
    </div>
  </header>
</section>
```